# ListView IllegalStateException for list without adding \ removing elements

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

As many others, I am getting IllegalStateException when using a ListView :(

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread

I know the basic explanation - I am probably trying to modify the list from background thread. After exploring my code over and over again, I cant find a place that I am actually doing that. I am not adding \ removing elements from the list - it is static, and does not change from creation.
What I AM doing is only modifying the **internal** data of the list's elements from a worker thread - but I am not sure if it is actually my problem.
so - this is my question - is it allowed to modify the underneath data of the list elements from background thread as long as I do not modify the list itself by adding \ removing elements?

**Update:**
Well I guess you are right, so here is a pseudo code:

```
//from main GUI thread.
ArrayList<People> namesList = // create and populate the list...
//lets assume that NamesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<People>
NamesArrayAdapter adapter = new NamesArrayAdapter(context, listViewResource, namesList); //instantiate the list adapter


//from backgroung thread
namesList.getItem(0).setName("et"); //Modifying existing element inside the list - is this ligal???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I AM doing is only modifying the internal data of the list's elements from a worker thread`

Is it the same static list as you set in `Adapter`?

Then you can not change them from `Background Thread`. If you change them then make sure you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: M Mohsin Naeem, thank you for the reply. Do I need to call this method from the background thread? and should I do that right before or after the update? I mean, theoretically, there could be a context switch right between the update and before the call to notifyDataSetChanged. Would it not be a problem?

Comment: to avoid any confusion always set a private List to the adapter.And when you done with the changes call a method say..`updateContent` on `UI thread` in that method update your adapter's private List and call `notifyDataSetChanged`